# Error when moving XAMLs to a Class Library (Windows store app)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I am trying to move all XAML pages to a Class Library (Windows store app).

When I call the Navigation function from the App using a class defined in the library, fore example:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ItemsPage1));
```

I get "XAML parsing failed."

The problem seems to be related with the styles or resources but I am not sure.

What I am missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Remove the period from the namespace and assembly names in your class library.

See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2739194

It seems crazy MSFT didn't fix this in Update1 since it's been a serious known bug since VS2012 was released.

An alternative fix is to keep the period(s) intact, but make sure the "Assembly name" and "Default namespace" fields match in the class library property page.